# How do I make this small, but simple food questionnaire work?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to make a simple food game/questionnaire, and the code keeps printing both lines. I want to have it print one or the other, and no matter what I try, I get the same end result. I am also using `Tkinter`. (Those of you that do not know, don't worry... This is for those that know what `Tkinter` does/is.)

Here is my code:

```
def Waffles():

    input ("Do you like Waffles?          ")
    if input is not ('yes'):
        print ("Ok, so you don't like Waffles...")
    input ("Do you like Pancakes?             ")
    if input is not ('no'):
        print ("Then let's fix some!!!")
    if input is ("no") or ("No"):
        print ("Ok, so you don't like Pancakes...")
    input ("Do you like French Toast?          ")
    if input is not ("no"):
        print ("Then let's fix some!!!")
    if input is not 'yes':
        food = input ("Then what do you like?         ")
        print ("Oh! Ok.")
```

Here is what gets printed:

```
Do you like Waffles?          no
Ok, so you don't like Waffles...
Do you like Pancakes?             no
Then let's fix some!!!
Ok, so you don't like Pancakes...
Do you like French Toast?          no
Then let's fix some!!!
Then what do you like?         food
Oh! Ok.
```

Can you help me make this print one or the other? ("Then let's fix some!!!" and "Do you like __________").

Comment: The code above has _nothing_ to do with [tag:tkinter].

Comment: I fixed the tag, but this code is in a Tkinter window as a button... So, I added it with Tkinter.

Comment: "Yes, I did my research" No, you didn't. If you had, you would know that that's not even close to how `input` works. See [here](https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html). And also, [don't use `is` to compare strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: you need to capture the results of the input function as a variable

Comment: I am very very basic at using python, thank you for the input.

Comment: `True or anything` is always `True`, and `("no")` is _never_ `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would've written it:

```
def waffles():

    response = input("Do you like Waffles?\t\t\t")
    print(response.lower())
    if response.lower() != "yes":
        print("Ok, so you don't like Waffles...")

        response = input("Do you like Pancakes?\t\t\t")
        if response.lower() != "no":
            print("Then let's fix some!!!")
        else:
            print("Ok, so you don't like Pancakes...")
            response = input("Do you like French Toast?\t\t")
            if response.lower() != "no":
                print("Then let's fix some!!!")
            if response.lower() != "yes":
                input("Then what do you like?\t\t\t")
                print ("Oh! Ok.")

waffles()
```

Comment: What do you mean by \t\t\t

Comment: @I_Like_PI That's the `tab` character for aligning strings better.

Comment: Here is the new code (total program)

Comment: from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def Waffles(): 
    input ("Do you like Waffles?          ")
    if answer is "False":
        print ("Ok, so you don't like Waffles...")
    input ("Do you like Pancakes?             ")
    if answer is "yes" or "Yes":
        print ("Then let's fix some!!!")
    elif answer is "False":
        print ("Ok, so you don't like Pancakes...")
    input ("Do you like French Toast?          ")
    if answer is "False":
        print ("Then let's fix some!!!")
    elif answer is  "True":
...

Comment: elif answer is  "True":
        food = input ("Then what do you like?         ")
        print ("Oh! Ok.") #works like it is supposed to (THIS LINE ONLY)

Comment: character limit on comments...

Comment: Thank you so much Nae for the help!!! the `waffles()` part didn't help... It was supposed to run, when the user pressed a button in Tkinter, but I got it to work...

Answer (score 1):

"input" is a function.  So you are testing if the built-in function is (or is not) various strings, which it never is.

You need to store the result of "input" in a variable and test that.  Here's a simplified version of `Waffles()` demonstrating the concept.

```
def Waffles():
  answer = input ("Do you like Waffles?          ")
  if answer != 'yes':
      print ("Ok, so you don't like Waffles...")
```

In case that isn't clear, here's a more contrived function that should really drive the example home.

```
def demonstrate_input():
    input("do you like waffles          ")
    print(input)
    answer = input("do you like waffles? I will remember this time         ")
    print(answer)
```

Here's what happens when you run that function:

```
do you like waffles          no
<built-in function input>
do you like waffles? I will remember this time         nope
nope
```

Note how printing "input" prints out a strange looking reference to the function, but printing "answer" returns the thing that was answered to the input prompt.